# docker doesn't reflect code change in docker container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have a Django application that runs in the Docker container locally on Mac machine. This docker container is managed via docker-compose. Django application is configured to reload if its code changes.

However, and this is a problem, when I change application code, Django default server reloads service, but changes are not reflected in the container. API response doesn't change. Here is my docker configuration:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential

COPY requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/build.txt

# copy app source into image
COPY service_api /opt/service_api
COPY manage.py /opt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  service-django:
    image: service-django
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./service_api/:/opt/service_api/service_api     # this path is correct!
    container_name: service-django
    hostname: service-django
    restart: always
```

- Docker desktop: 3.5.0
- Docker Engine: 20.10.7
- Compose: 1.29.2
- Big Sur: 11.4

**Any help will be appreciated!**

Answer (score 2):

You would either inject your code into the container during the build time using that `COPY service_api /opt/service_api` in your Dockerfile (which is not what you want here, since it kinda burns the source code into the image) or going for another approach (which is desired here) which is to bind your source code directory as a volume into the container, which enables the modifications you make into your source code to be visible inside the container, hence allowing code updates to be applied by Django server reload (As you're doing the exact thing in your compose file)

So all thing you need to do here is to remove copying files during build time and let your source code to be visible only through that volume.

Comment: I tried proposed approach and move all code load from Docker to docker-compose but no luck

Comment: @user2536982 Did you remove that `COPY` line from Dockerfile and built the image again?

Comment: yep. I moved all files manipulation from Docker to docker-compose.